# How to get the coordinates from the location I touch the touchscreen on every objects even on textfields

Tags: swift

I want to get the location of touched in screen. I searched the internet and found this code:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let location = touch.location(in: nil)
        print(location)
    }
```

but it doesn't works when user touch some fields like textField or tableViewCell.
How can i do that?

Comment: Instead of passing `nil` pass any `UIView` or `self`

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I use `self.view` but it doesn't work either

Comment: Can you show your view hierarchy?

Comment: try `touch.view?`